# I am receiving nil values in my small recursion method

Tags: ruby, recursion, multidimensional-array, null

The basic premise of the method is for the argument array to take a multidimensional array and snake around the matrix clockwise pushing all values into arr and returning them as a list of integers.

However,I seem to be receiving this error:

```
 `block in snail': undefined method `reverse' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

This is my method:

```
def snail(array)

arr = []
 loop do
    return arr.flatten if array.empty?
    arr << array.shift
    array.map {|row| arr << row.pop}
    arr << array.pop.reverse
    array.map {|row| arr << row.shift}

  end

end
```

This is the test argument:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]
```

This is the output i get when i edit line 5 to this:

```
line 5: arr << unless NilClass then array.pop.reverse end
output: [1, 2, 3, 6, 9, nil, 4, 7, 5, 8, nil, nil]
```

Expected return:

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4, 5]
```

Why are these nil values appearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that on your second iteration, `array` becomes empty after `arr << array.shift` so the next two lines are executing on an empty array. The error you're seeing is because `array.pop` on the eighth line of the method has nothing to pop and so returns `nil` and `nil` does not support `#reverse`.

You need to handle that `array` can become depleted at any stage, not just after all four operations are executed.

```
def snail(array)
  arr = []
  until array.flatten.empty?
    arr << array.shift
    array.map {|row| arr << row.pop} unless array.flatten.empty?
    arr << array.pop.reverse unless array.flatten.empty?
    array.map {|row| arr << row.shift} unless array.flatten.empty?
  end
  return arr.flatten
end
```

Incidentally... I think the snail going back up on the left side is not correctly coded.  You have to read the numbers from bottom to top, so, the last line of the loop should be...

```
array.reverse.map {|row| arr << row.shift} unless array.flatten.empty?
```

The problem doesn't show on your test argument but you'll see the issue if you try a larger matrix, like

[[1,2,3,4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]

Your method gives...
[1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 12, 16, 15, 14, 13, 5, 9, 6, 7, 11, 10]

But correct answer is...
[1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 12, 16, 15, 14, 13, 9, 5, 6, 7, 11, 10]

Comment: Ahh I thought the loop breaking when array.flatten.empty? was enough to safeguard against an empty array. So nil is returned before the loop breaks? It worked anyway. Thanks!

Comment: The `array.flatten.empy?` break is ok but the array could become empty at ANY step, not necessarily after the last step of four.  Also, note the edit I've just done... there's a teeny problem with the algorithm.

Comment: Ahh yeah, I noticed that last night when I wrote a couple more tests thanks a lot. I never realized that it only checks if the arrays empty after all the steps are completed. It makes logical sense I suppose.